# In CakePHP the multiple select box is not getting multiple selected based on passed array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, drop-down-menu

The problem is that I am not able to multiple select in the multiple select box based on the array that I am using in the form helper.From the controller I have passed an array called  $selected_colors to the view. This is done as shown below-

```
$this->set(compact('colors', 'selected_colors'));
```

On `debug($selected_colors);` the $selected_colors is the below given array-

```
array(
(int) 0 => '1',
(int) 2 => '20',
(int) 4 => '21'
)
```

The form helper that I am using in the view is as given below-

```
$this->Form->input('MasterArticle.0.color_id', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => true, 'options' => $colors, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'input-xlarge', 'selected' => $selected_colors));
```

Please help me solving the problem.

Comment: Why your selected_colors array jumps from 0 to 2 and from 2 to 4?

Comment: Have you tried to create the elements in the  `selected_colors` array without quotes?  `0=>1`, `1=>20`...

Comment: the keys of your find(list) or whatever need to be the values here.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a known bug in CakePHP < 2.3.1. I have stumbled on it too. It has been fixed in CakePHP 2.3.1.

Comment: Or not, I have the same problem with 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Use default keyword as given below:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Article.tags',array('options'=>$tags,'type'=>'select','label'=>'TDSP','class'=>'distributeSelect','multiple'=> 'true','selected' => $selected));?>
```

Comment: tried to format the code (not overly successful ;-) please edit and improve

Comment: Or leverage the controller to set default values - as I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$this->Form->input('MasterArticle.0.color_id', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => true, 'options' => $colors, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'input-xlarge', 'default' => $selected_colors));
```

Please vote if this answer is correct

Comment: Please peovide an explanation what you have changed.